# Accessing public ObservableCollection in another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection, public

I have a public class `BoolStringClass` defined in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public class BoolStringClass
{
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I use this class to define an `ObservableCollection` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public ObservableCollection<BoolStringClass> BoolStringList { get; set; }
```

New lines are added to `BoolStringList` in a `private void` on the click of a button:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool boolKeyValue = true;
    BoolStringList.Add(new BoolStringClass() { IsSelected = boolKeyValue, OptionName = "BingWeather" });
    BoolStringList.Add(new BoolStringClass() { IsSelected = boolKeyValue, OptionName = "Cortana" });
}
```

`BoolStringList` is used to dynamically create `CheckBox` in a `ListBox` in `MainWindow.xaml` which works fine ([image of MainWindow working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl14h.png)):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BoolStringList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding OptionName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

A new window `SecondWindow` is created and made openable by a `private void` button click in `MainWindow`, and the `Listbox` above is added to `SecondWindow.xaml`, where the listbox displays no checkboxes before or after the addition of data to `BoolStringList` ([image of SecondWindow not displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRU6n.png)).

How can `SecondWindow.xaml` access the `ObservableCollection` named `BoolStringList` defined in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`?

Comment: It is not clear how you pass data to the SecondWindow. Generally, you just need to pass your ObservableCollection to the ViewModel of the SecondWindow, then you will be able to access it from xaml in SecondWindow.

Comment: How is this done? I tried `public static Application Current { get; }` from [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ms600304(v=vs.95)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) without success, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: it is not clear at all what you want shown on the second window or what your actual problem is. Be very clear on 1) what is your desired behavior and 2) what is the current behavior

Comment: @chancea That's what the two images are for. The first image is the intended behaviour with a list of checkboxes, and the second image is the current behaviour with no checkboxes. This occurs when the xaml is in a different window from where `BoolStringList` is defined as stated in the second last paragraph.

Comment: The second window is supposed to be an exact duplicate of the first?

Comment: @chancea The checkboxes being created in the first window are supposed to be visible in the second window. The exact same `xaml` is used in both windows. In the example code I removed the parsing for checkbox parameters and the grid with the label because they aren't relevant to the question, but the label in the second image is not part of the problem. I can replace the images with the text in the example code if it makes it clearer.

Comment: If you want both windows to use the same list, you need for the same list object's reference to be shared between them. See duplicate for some examples. If you still can't figure it out, post a new question in which you've provided a proper [mcve] that shows what you've tried, along with a clear explanation of what the code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out. See also [ask] for information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Those examples state how to reference objects in the `.cs` of the second window but not how to format them to be accepted in the `.xaml`. Using the second answer defining everything in `app.xaml.cs`, it is still not clear how I bind the object in `.xaml`.

Secondly, I'm not sure how to make the code more minimal than it is. I stated what I have, then what it should look like, then what it looks like when I make a single change which I described, and I then asked how to make it work with that change. Would it be clearer if the code was an entire example of each window?

Comment: _"I'm not sure how to make the code more minimal than it is"_ -- please read [mcve]. Please remember that your example needs to be both **minimal** _and_ **complete**. Make sure that in your post, you ask the question _you actually want the answer to_. The question you've posted here is _"How can SecondWindow.xaml access the ObservableCollection named BoolStringList"_, not anything to do with formatting. The duplicate (and many other similar questions with answers) address that question just fine.